# JAVAFX Como alterar a label depois da construção do FXML?

Tags: javafx, label, text

Tenho uma label no scene B. Quero mudar essa label quando o usuário clicar no botão "Login" da primeira tela. Eu tentei fazer isso no meu projeto com o `usuario.setText()` (usuario é o nome da label), mas como a label é construída após o comando de alteração, a alteração não é efetuada e ocorre um erro. Como faço para alterar a label depois dela ter sido construída e existir no JavaFX?

```
@FXML
void RegisterLogin(ActionEvent event) // Evento ao clicar no botão no Scene A.

{

 MessageController msgcont = new MessageController(); //Instanciação do Scene B;
 msgcont.usuario.setText("Teste"); //Label do Scene B;

}
```

A alteração `msgcont.usuario.setText("Teste");` não ocorre.

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual o seu código? Qual erro aparece? Sem essas informações vai ser difícil alguém conseguir dar uma boa resposta

Comment: Editei. Desculpa.

Comment: Sem problemas, não precisa se desculpar

Answer (score 0):

Na sua classe de Aplicação de MessageController, crie uma referencia para sua classe de Controller para poder alterar e passar objetos para ela, pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Principal extends Application {

//Criando um atributo para acessar o Controller da aplicação
public static PrincipalController controller ;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    this.controller = (PrincipalController) loader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root)
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Depois, na sua classe de Controller, crie um atributo para receber o objeto que quer alterar. No seu caso seria uma String para alterar o Label.

```
private String usuarioLogado
```

No Controller do Login, após verificar as credenciais do usuário, instancie a classe MessageController a variável desejada, e sete seu valor:

```
@FXML
private void actionBtnLogar(ActionEvent event) {
//....
    try {
        usuario = this.verificaCredencias(login, senha);
        if (usuario) {
           Principal prin = new Principal ();
           prin.start(new Stage());
           prin.controller.setUsuarioLogado("usuario");
           Login.fechar();
        } else {
            //tratar
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //tratar
    }
}
```

Finalmente, crie uma função na Classe MessageController para alterar Label desejado. Essa função deve ser executada após o método initialize da classe de Controller.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Os atributos também podem ser anotados com @FXML, e você pode acessá-los dessa forma também desde que coloque o id certinho no SceneBuilder.